# Joining two tables using pandasql

Tags: python, sql, pandas, join, pandasql

I am running SQL queries in Python using Pandasql. The queries x, y and z work fine but u gives an error

```
x = pysql("select * from flight f left join iata i on f.ORIGIN = i.IATA;")

y = pysql("select * from flight f inner join iata i on f.ORIGIN = i.IATA;")

z = pysql("select * from flight, iata where flight.ORIGIN = iata.IATA;")

u = pysql("select * from flight f, iata i where f.ORIGIN = i.IATA;")
```

**The error message is**

PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: iata [SQL: 'select * from flight f, iata i where f.ORIGIN = i.IATA;']

**Question**: What is wrong with u? It looks like we can use aliases in a join without mentioning left, right, inner etc. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you must explicitly alias it with **AS** when using old style joins

instead

```
select * from flight f, iata i where f.ORIGIN = i.IATA;
```

write

```
select * from flight AS f, iata AS i where f.ORIGIN = i.IATA;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
u = pysql("SELECT * from flight f join iata i on (f.ORIGIN = i.IATA);")
```